# Ways to access class structure/adding or removing highlighting via eclipse.jdt.ls Plugin API

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-jdt, language-server-protocol

I want to expand the Java LSP server(jdt.ls) but I didn't find detailed documentation for it. I want to
-  access methods/annotations of classes;
-  add/turn off error highlighting in some cases.

Are there any ways to do this? I will be glad to any examples.

Comment: Do you have to use an LSP server? An Eclipse plug-in can use JDT APIs directly, for example see [here](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJDT/article.html)